# Why my PC won't boot up?

Tags: windows-7, boot, memory, graphics-card, motherboard

Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-H61M-DS2 (OnBoard Graphics)
Core: Intel i5 3350P (No Graphics Included)
RAM: Kingston KVR13N9S8/4

When I press the power button, the only thing that the PC does is "buzzing" (as in the sound it makes when it has no RAM installed, that annoying long "beep"). What would may be the problem? It drives me crazy! I've never seen such thing before and I'm in a desperate need of you people!

Comment: Keep going with the information in the question (edited in). When did this begin to happen? Is this a new build? Has it ever booted up? Have you recently changed anything? When you say "the only thing it does" Is the PSU going on? Do the fans kick in or even burp once?  Anything else you can relay. What are the internal conditions? Is it dusty? Did you check the board over for any visable signs (like capicitors bulging, componets charred)?  Is the CPU mounted proper, Which can include a Poorly mounted or broken mount on a heatsync.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I expect you have two RAM modules inserted.

Possible reasons of beeping:

1. one of RAM modules is faulty
2. board does not like the particular RAM module in particular RAM slot
3. board is faulty

at first try to swap position of your RAM modules, then try only one of RAM modules in both  RAM slots, then try to use different RAM module, then return the board to reseller because of faulty RAM controller.